# Given 2 arrays a and b, return an array that represent sum of a and b

Tags: javascript

Constraight:

- 1 <= a.length,  b.length <= 50
- 0 <= a[i], b[i] <= 9
  Example 1:

```
a = [1, 0]
b = [5]

// results
sum = [1, 5]
```

Example 2:

```
a = [3, 2]
b = [1, 6]

// results
sum = [4, 8]
```

Example 3:

```
a = [4, 2, 3]
b = [4, 8]

// results
sum = [4, 7, 1]
```

It mean that 123 + 99 = 222 when we write down is here

```
 123
+
  99
------
 222
```

And here is my solution

```
const add = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    while (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
      arr2 = [0].concat(arr2);
    }
  } else {
    while (arr2.length > arr1.length) {
      arr1 = [0].concat(arr1);
    }
  }
  arr1=arr1.reverse();
  arr2=arr2.reverse();
  return arr1.map((x, index) => {
    let final = 0;
    let surplus = +((x + (arr2[index] % 100)) / 10).toString().split(".")[0];
    let result = +((x + (arr2[index] % 100)) / 10).toString().split(".")[1];
    if (x + arr2[index] >= 10) {
      final+=result
      arr2[index]
    }
    else{
        if(index-1>=0){
        final+=arr1[index]+arr2[index]+surplus;
    }
    }
    return final;
  }).reverse();
};
```

And my test case

```
a = [1, 2, 3]; 
b = [9, 9];
```

But got:

```
[1, 1, 2]
```

Expected result is:

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: The problem description does not make sense, especially "Example 3"

Comment: @Pointy Example 3: `423 + 48 = 471`

Comment: @Andreas ah OK, so the array represents the digits of a number in base 10 notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert to number, add the values and get an array as result.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => Array.from((+a.join('') + +b.join('')).toString(), Number)

console.log(add([4, 2, 3], [4, 8]));
console.log(add([1, 2, 3], [9, 9]));
```

Because of the large numbers, you may need to convert to [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => Array.from((BigInt(a.join('')) + BigInt(b.join(''))).toString(), Number)

console.log(add([4, 2, 3], [4, 8]));
console.log(add([1, 2, 3], [9, 9]));
```

Comment: "Best answer" wouldn't just squash everything into one line without any further explanations (like implicit number parsing, why `Array.from()`, what that `Number` thing does in the `Array.from()` call) - imho...

Comment: @Andreas, come on. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is no rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution without using BigInt

```
const fillArr = (arr, num) => {
  if (!num) return arr;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.unshift(0);
  }
  return arr;
};

const sum = (a, b) => {
  a = a.length > b.length ? a : fillArr(a, Math.abs(a.length - b.length));
  b = b.length > a.length ? b : fillArr(b, Math.abs(a.length - b.length));
  let mem = 0,
    res = [];
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let resString = (a[i] + b[i] + mem + "").split("");
    if (a[i] + b[i] + mem > 9) {
      res.unshift(+resString[1]);
      mem = 1;
    } else {
      res.unshift(+resString[0]);
      mem = 0;
    }
  }
  if (mem != 0) {
    res.unshift(mem);
  }
  return res;
};
```